# What does it mean for a jwt token to expire

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm implementing jwt token for user verification purposes. I sign a jwt token whenever a user sign-ins and store that token in my database. Then whenever the user wants to access their personal information, they send me their token and I check if such token exists in the database, if it does, I allow access (please reccommend if you know better ways for user verification). The thing is, I want my token to expire every 24 hours, which means every 24 hours I want the token in my database to become an empty string, however I did some experiments:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var token = jwt.sign({d:'tt'}, 'prvateKey', {expiresIn: 1000});
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(token)
}, 3000)
```

the code above console logs the actual token instead of an empty string,  null, or something like that.
So is my code somewhat wrong or does expiration mean something different than what I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jwt.sign`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) returns the token as a string. This will not automatically become empty on expiry, it's just a string. However, the token will become invalid. You can check token validity using the [`jwt.verify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) method. `jwt.verify` will error if the token is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `expiresIn` option is a convenience to set the token `exp` claim. This is what the jwt spec says about this claim:

*The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.*

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4

The `jsonwebtoken` package documentation also says:

*`expiresIn`: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span zeit/ms.*

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim

With the `jsonwebtoken` package, an expired token actually translates in the `verify()` function throwing an exception with a `TokenExpiredError` name when passing it the `token` for processing.

```
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
var data = {
    "data": "some data"
}
var secret = "secret"
var token = jwt.sign({ data }, secret, { expiresIn: 1 })

setTimeout(function () {
    try {
        var payload = jwt.verify(token, secret)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.name)   // output: TokenExpiredError
    }
}, 1000)
```